# Hiding unused/remaining rows and specific amount of columns excel python

Tags: python, excel, hide, xlsxwriter, xlwt

So i successfully wrote my first excel file using python and xlwt. Now, i would like to add to my code. I would like for the remaining rows (the unused rows, or a range that i could enter) to be hidden and the same for columns. Is it at all possible to do this with xlwt? If not, is it possible to do it with using xlsxwriter after creating the file with xlwt in the same script? I'm lost as to how to do this. 
One line that i have that is giving me problems right now:

```
    My_Sheet = wb.add_sheet(All_Sheets[0,count],cell_overwrite_ok=True)    
    My_Sheet.set_default_row(hide_unused_rows=True)
```

This gives me the following error: "AttributeError: 'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'set_default_row' "

Answer (score 2):

Now, you have an error because [xlsxwriter](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html) and [xlwt](http://xlwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html) worksheet objects haven't `set_default_row` method. You can read more about `woksheet` classes by link reference for each-library.

So, you can look into [google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/python-excel), and `xlwt` examples from this [site](http://www.python-excel.org/) for more information.

You can hide cells in `xlsxwriter` by this way:

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook   = xlsxwriter.Workbook('filename.xlsx')

worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
worksheet.write('C3', "Abracadabra!")
worksheet.set_row(2, 2,[], {'hidden': True})

workbook.close()
```

or in `xlwt`:

```
import xlwt

workbook = xlwt.Workbook()
worksheet = workbook.add_sheet('Sheet')

worksheet.write(4, 0, "Abracadabra!")
worksheet.row(4).hidden = 1

workbook.save('filename.xlsx')
```

In `xlwt` you also can hid `Column` objects by this way, but i'm not sure about `Cells` objects.